# Fixing my navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation

I'm working on a navigation bar and am having a problem. This is my current [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmeVh.png). I'm floating the group on the right to the right, but I want everything to be on the same row. How do I do this?

```
nav {
margin: 0px 10%;
}
#floatedright {
float: right;
}
#floatedright > li {
float: left;
}
</style>
<body>
<section id="headercontainer">
  <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">PiercaNrla</a></li>
        <section id="floatedright">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get something like this?

```
<body>
  <style>
    nav {
      margin: 0px 10%;
    }

    #floatedright {
      float: right;
    }

    #headercontainer ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <section id="headercontainer">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">PiercaNrla</a></li>
        <section id="floatedright">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
</body>
```

I took your code snippet and tried to piece it together since there are some missing closing tags. Hopefully I guessed correctly. If you provide the whole of the code, I might be more helpful.

Comment: Great! If you go ahead and accept the answer, we can call it resolved.